# IUPAC name of Dewar benzene

Tags: nomenclature, resonance

Dewar benzene according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewar_benzene) has the IUPAC name **bicyclo[2.2.0]hexa-2,5-diene**.

Is it correct to give this name because resonance takes place and if we fix a certain numbering, as resonance takes place, a different carbon would occupy that numbering in a cyclic manner? Similarly like saying benzene's IUPAC name is *cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene* would be wrong.

Kindly clarify.

Comment: There's no resonance in it and otherwise it would still be no problem.

Comment: @Mithoron could you elaborate on this as a full answer?